# The table "users" for active record class "Users" cannot be found in the database YII

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

[image]i have tried to call a function (`getMenu()`) in `CommonFunction.php` (location : components/CommonFunction.php) , which will return some user data, but when i transferred my application from godaddy (shared hosting) to resellerclub (shared hosting) , following error showing.

The table "users" for active record class "Users" cannot be found in the database

1. table exists in database
2. letter case for file and class name for model checked
3. using the correct db connection
4. created a function (say `abc()`) in `CommonFunctions.php`  which is successfully fetching user information.
5. when tried to call above mentioned abc() from getMenu() , it again showing above error
6. am able to call the `getMenu` function from my other controllers but there is not issue for that
7. But when i tried to call getMenu from this specific function it is showing error
8. If assigned a static value to first fetching, it will show error for the next fetching in the same function .

`commonFunction.php`

```
   public static function GetMenu($user_id = 0) {

    $user_info = Users::model()->findByPk($user_id);
    if (!isset($user_info) || count($user_info) < 1)
        return;
    $user_profile = UserProfile::model()->find('user_id=:user_id', array(':user_id' => $user_id));
    $creteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $creteria->condition = "contributor=\"$user_info->user_name\"";
    $photo_upload_count = Godown::model()->count($creteria);

    $creteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $creteria->condition = "user_email=\"$user_info->email\"";
    $photo_purchase_count = Downloads::model()->count($creteria);

    //echo $photo_purchase_count; exit;
    $creteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $creteria->condition = "contributor_user_name=\"$user_info->user_name\"";
    $photo_sale_count = Downloads::model()->count($creteria);
    //echo $photo_sale_count; exit;

    $base = Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true);
    $profile_pic_org = false;
    $profile_dummy = "$base/images/profile-img.jpg";
    if (isset($user_profile->profile_pic) && $user_profile->profile_pic != '') {
        $profile_pic_url = "$base/profile-pic/thumb/" . $user_profile->profile_pic;
        $profile_pic_org = "$base/profile-pic/" . $user_profile->profile_pic;
    } else {
        $profile_pic_url = "$base/images/profile-img.jpg";
        $profile_pic_org = "$base/images/profile-img.jpg";
    }
    if (isset($user_profile) && count($user_profile) > 0) { // profile for the user is almost complete , we can fetch that info too;
        $name = $user_profile->first_name . ' ' . $user_profile->last_name;
    } else {
        $a=explode('@', $user_info->email);
        $name = reset($a);
    }
    if ($user_info->user_type == 'c') { // find the statics if and only if the user is a contributor
        $creteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $creteria->condition = "contributor=\"$user_info->user_name\" and display_status =\"\"";
        $photo_pending_approval_count = Godown::model()->count($creteria);

        $creteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $creteria->condition = "contributor=\"$user_info->user_name\" and display_status =\"N\"";
        $photo_rejected_count = Godown::model()->count($creteria);

        $creteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $creteria->condition = "contributor=\"$user_info->user_name\" and display_status =\"Y\"";
        $photo_accepted_count = Godown::model()->count($creteria);
        $folder = self::GetUploadFolder($user_id);
        $folder = $folder['orginal'];
        $penging_file_count = 0;
        //echo $folder; exit;

    }
```

Comment: why are you shouting over the internet? nobody can hear you.

Comment: Are you caching your db schema?

Comment: @willemRezema,  am not caching db schema

Comment: findByPK returns null or object, so check again your code "count($user_info) < 1"

Comment: @crafter,  findByPk throwing error as mentioned above,

Comment: @DeepuThomas Have you checked that the cases for the `tableName` in `Users.php` and the database match? I got this error when moving code from Windows to Linux.

Comment: @topher yes  ii have checked that